# Gerar setters apenas no construtor da classe ou gerar fora do construtor

Tags: java, classes, getters-setters

Nas classes em Java, é comum *(ao menos na faculdade só vejo assim)* criar atributos privados e gerar **getters** e **setters** para esses atributos.

Mas, eu li que pode-se fazer algo um pouco diferente: gerar apenas os **getters** e deixar os **setters** no construtor.

Na minha cabeça, deixando os setters no construtor, acho que o código ficará mais fácil de ser entendido e mais fácil de dar manutenção..

Fazendo conforme essa segunda opção, deixar os **setters** no construtor, é uma boa prática (ou até mesmo é a melhor prática) para se aplicar na construção das classes? Ou criar gets e sets para todos os atributos é mais recomendado?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode perfeitamente não prover nenhum método *setter* público para um atributo caso assim deseje, o que não é recomendado é deixar o atributo como público, pois se um dia você resolver mudá-lo para privado e atribuir alguma validação à ele você poderá estar quebrando o código de outras classes que acessam o atributo diretamente, sem utilizar o *setter*.

Se você deixar o atributo como privado e não disponibilizar o *setter* não há nenhum problema nisso, inclusive se um dia resolver adicionar um *setter* público, pois você não estará quebrando nenhuma classe desse jeito.

Em resumo, você pode sim fazer isso, desde que seja apropriado para sua aplicação, você não é obrigado a implementar *getters* e *setters* sempre.

Answer (score 6):

Isso deve variar conforme a funcionalidade de sua classe.

Os atributos dessa sua classe precisam ser alterados logo no construtor? Veja que não é preciso conter todos os atributos como parâmetros de seu construtor, irá depender do objetivo da classe. Você pode definir um valor padrão no construtor para eles sem tê-los recebidos como parâmetro.

Outra pergunta seria, esses atributos poderão ser alterados durante a execução do programa? Getters e setters, em resumo, estão atrelados a ideia de **encapsulamento**.

Veja que varia de implementação pra implementação, objetivo para objetivo. De qualquer forma isso não faz com que não conter setter para um atributo seja melhor prática ou não, é necessário avaliar caso a caso.

Abraço!

Answer (score 5):

Apesar de já haver boas respostas, com boas explicações, não teve exemplos para exemplificar a questão, então vou postar minha resposta com um exemplo simples para tentar agregar valor a questão.

Considerando a seguinte estrutura de `class`:

```
public class ClazzTest {

    private long id;
    private String nome;
    private long atributoImutavel;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public long getAtributoImutavel() {
        return atributoImutavel;
    }

    public ClazzTest(long id, String nome, long atributoImutavel) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.atributoImutavel = atributoImutavel;
    }
}
```

Onde o atributo 'atributoImutavel', não possui `setter` e somente pode ser setado pelo construtor.

Agora considere a seguinte `class` que utiliza e manipula a class 'ClazzTest':

```
public class UtilizaClazzTest {

    public void manipulaClazzTest(){
        ClazzTest clazzTest = new ClazzTest(1 /* id */, "Test" /* nome */, 10 /* atributo imutavel */);
        clazzTest.setId(3);
        clazzTest.setNome("Fernando");
        // mas não consigo setar o atributo imutavel
    }
}
```

Então se eu somente crio o `getter` `public` de um atributo e somente permito instanciar(setar) o atributo no construtor, ele não será mutável pela instancia, seu valor só poderá ser setado no momento em que ele for criado.

Mas, isso não é uma abordagem incorreta, pelo contrario, é muito utilizada para fins específicos, por exemplo se você realmente quer garantir que o atributo só possa ser setado no momento da criação do objeto.

> Obs: No exemplo, o atributo 'atributoImutavel' poderia até mesmo utilizar o 'operador' (não sei se essa é a definição) `final` assim:

```
private final long atributoImutavel;
```

Assim você estaria garantindo que o atributo apenas seria setado no momento da instanciação e não poderia mais ser setado por nenhum método interno da `class`, tornando-o assim verdadeiramente 'imutavel' após sua criação.

Mas assim, como citou [@Math em sua resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/28264/2998):

> *"Você pode perfeitamente não prover nenhum método setter público para um atributo caso assim deseje"*

Só que tem que saber/entender o por que de estar fazendo isso.

Por isso que na faculdade como você citou, é ensinado a sempre criar os `getters` e `setters`, pois em 99% dos casos de entidades de negocio é assim que será, então por default é atributo `private` e `getters` e `setters`.

Não sei se ficou bem 'exemplificável'.

Comment: Sim. Ficou muito 'exemplificável' e claro. Obrigado!